# Prestashop 404 Page Not Found isn't loading properly

Tags: http-status-code-404, smarty, prestashop

I'm working on a prestashop website and were almost there, but for some reason the 404 page isnt displaying properly and I can't figure out why.

http://www.exclusivetech.co.uk/pagenotfound

Can anyone explain why it would do this?

Heres the PageNotFoundController

```
class PageNotFoundControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = '404';
    public $page_name = 'pagenotfound';

    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');
        parent::initContent();

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'404.tpl');
    }

    public function canonicalRedirection($canonical_url = '')
    {
        // 404 - no need to redirect to the canonical url
    }
}
```

Here's the 404.tpl, havent touched it just their default.

```
<h1>{l s='Page not available'}</h1>

    <p>
        {l s='Were sorry, but the Web address you entered is no longer available'}
    </p>

    <h3>{l s='To find a product, please type its name in the field below'}</h3>
    <form action="{$link->getPageLink('search')}" method="post" class="std">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="search">{l s='Search our product catalog:'}</label>
                <input id="search_query" name="search_query" type="text" />
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK" class="button_small" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <a href="{$base_dir}" title="{l s='Home'}">{l s='Home'}</a>
```

Comment: Looks like the page footer for some reason has style "display: none".

Edit: Well, it did. Now it doesn't appear at all, but maybe you're restarting something?

Comment: Wow, I hate prestashop.. thank yo uso much for that, simple easy fix. If you put it as an answer i'll tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the page footer for some reason has style "display: none"

Comment: Most obvious answer there possibly could be ha, thanks again.. it's been a long day